# problem to fetch data from only filled input feilds of form in table with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch the data which is filled by the user in input fields of the form with the help of javascript but want to fetch only filled data in table and neglect the empty fields

Comment: Can you give example of what data is available and what is it that you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution, hope it works for you...
Suppose your input field's id is "name"
This is the javascript way:

```
var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
```

You can do the same using jQuery too:

```
var name=$('#name').val()
```

these values are passed in the variable called "name"...
Edit: Since you want to neglect the empty fields, you can keep a simple if/else condition and check empty fields like this:

```
if($('#name').val() == '')
{
    alert("Enter Your Name");
    return false;
}
```

you can keep whatever fits your situation inside the if condition...(: